# What happens when I run ln -s pear /tmp/pear-build-`whoami`

Tags: bash

I have read this interesting post regarding the installation of php-mongo driver [not writeable by the current user](http://www.jefferyvincent.com/archives/481)

```
mkdir pear
ln -s pear /tmp/pear-build-`whoami`
/usr/bin/pear config-set cache_dir $HOME/pear/cache
/usr/bin/pear config-set download_dir $HOME/pear/download
/usr/bin/pear config-set temp_dir $HOME/pear/temp
```

This makes pear compile it in your home directory instead of /tmp.

Then I ran:

```
pecl install mongo
```

What is the outcome of running the following command?

```
ln -s pear /tmp/pear-build-`whoami`
```

Answer (score 2):

A command surrounded by back-ticks is replaced by its output. So `` `whoami` `` gets replaced by `david` on my computer. (To see more information on `whoami`, run `man whoami`.)

So this command:

```
ln -s pear /tmp/pear-build-`whoami`
```

gets turned into this (depending on your username):

```
ln -s pear /tmp/pear-build-david
```

`ln` is a command to create hard links or symbolic links. The `-s` flags indicates that it will create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) pointing to `pear`. Its own filename is `/tmp/pear-build-david`.

I'm not sure why this step is necessary for pear, as it depends on how pear works internally.